# Timer start counting again after a button is touched (Swift)

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

I'm doing a "Quiz Game" and am trying to put a timer to the User has only 10 seconds to try to answer the question. If the 10 seconds are over, it will pop up an alert warning that take long to answer. But if the User touch the right answer before time runs out, I want the timer start new count. I'm trying in various ways and still did not get and also not found a question similar to my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the NSTimer().

Start timer:

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target:self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Handle Timer:

```
func update() {

seconds++

if seconds >= 10 {

    // alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Time Over", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "O.K.", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    // set seconds to 0
    seconds = 0

}}
```

Stop timer:

```
timer.invalidate()
```